# get char from console and convert it to int

Tags: java

try to create new method, but during running it's not working
code
this placed on

```
class Matrix {
    public static void main (String  args[]) throws IOException {
        ...
        System.out.println("Enter q-ty of matrix elements i= ");
        int gormatelement = 0;
        getchartoint (gormatelement);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and after method

```
public static void getchartoint (int a) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String k = bReader.readLine();
    a =  Integer.parseInt(k);
}
```

this code must get char from console and convert it to int - will be used as q-ty of elements in matrix

Comment: What's not working? And where are you invoking the method from? I mean, where is your first 3 lines of code placed?

Comment: what do you expect this code to do?

Comment: first 3 line placed in class Matrix {
 public static void main (String  args[]) throws IOException {

Comment: i expect that i get symbol from console as q-ty of matrix components

Comment: You shouldn't be tagging `throws IOException` all over your code. The Exception is used to deal with bad parameters and allows you to capture the event and deal with it accordingly. If you write a try/catch statement do you get an exception you can post here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the value of a simple parameter variable (like a) inside a method, it does not change the variable that you gave when you called the method (like gormatelement).

The easiest way to do this is to have the method return the integer value and the calling code to store it.

```
int gormatelement = getchartoint ();
```

and

```
public static int getchartoint () throws IOException{
   int a;
   ... same code ...
   return a;
}
```

**Expanded**

If you want to go look up more about this concept of passing variables, you can Google the terms "call by value" and "call by reference".

Java uses a "call by value" but it is easy to get confused when objects with contained instance variables are passed to a method because the contained field values can be changed and the change seems to propagate to the object you called the method with.

What's happening is that the value of an Object is really a reference to the obect's contents, so to speak. You have to think about it a while to see what I mean.

Comment: Good call. @Bki if you change your method statement to `public static int getchartoint(int a)` and replace the last line with `return Integer.parseInt(k);` you'll be able to use the variable in the function that called it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class x
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println("Enter q-ty of matrix elements i= ");
        int gormatelement = 0;
        getchartoint (gormatelement);
}

public static void getchartoint (int a) throws IOException{
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new 
                    InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String k = bReader.readLine();
                a =  Integer.parseInt(k);
            }
}
```

Since you are a beginner, At least this is required for your program to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the result of of parseInt() to a, which is a local copy of "gormatelement" and which is deleted once the function ends. Java uses ["call-by-value"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-by-value#Call_by_value) for primitive data types.

You could also take a look at the [Scanner Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
public static int getIntFromCommandLine() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    return scan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
int gormatelement = YourClass.getchartoint(0);
```